Why does the SJA1105QELY Ethernet Switch chip stop sending packets after it has sent 48,790 bytes
Why does the SJA1105QELY Ethernet Switch chip stop sending packets after it has sent 48,790 bytes?
I designed a circuit card containing the SJA1105 Ethernet Switch made by NXP.
After doing a reset and loading the static configuration tables, we can send packets into one port, and they exit the other port as they should.
This works fine up until 48,790 bytes have left the outgoing port.  After that point the statistics counters show bytes/good frames coming into the chip, but no more bytes/frames come out of any port.
I tested with various sized packets, and with various timings between the packets, and at various link speeds (100Mbps and 1Gbps).  None of those things seemed to affect the point at which the switch no longer transmits.  The only consistent factor is that it stops when a certain number of bytes have been sent.
Performing a soft reset and loading configs again allows me to send another 48,790 bytes and then it stops again.
I probed various error counters in the device but was unable to find any error flags that were set anywhere.  Having said that, I haven't probed every error register, so there could be a flag set somewhere.
The error registers I looked at were...

N_CRCERR0 - N_CRCERR3
PORT_STATUS_MII0 - PORT_STATUS_MII3
N_MAC_DIAG_CNT0 - N_MAC_DIAG_CNT3
N_MAC_DIAG_FLG0 - N_MAC_DIAG_FLG3
GENERAL_STATUS0 - GENERAL_STATUS11
Vlan Memory Partition Status 0 -7
Vlan Memory Partiition Error Count 0 -7
L2 Memory Partition Status 0-7 L2
Memory Partition Error Count 0 -7

Since it seems to be based purely on number of bytes sent, my first guesses are that it would be something related to a queue running out of memory.  Or a policer block counting a certain number of bytes.  But nothing obvious stands out.

Have you asked NXP support?

I may, but they can take a while to get back to you.  Last time I did it, it took several weeks to get answers about all the missing information in their UM11040 document, and then they released a new version of it not long after my queries.
